# NSlog() to NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nslog

I want to take an NSLog() message and save it as a NSString.

For example, the following prints something like "Player coordinates (0,0)"

```
NSLog(@"Player cordinates(%i, %i)", xcord, ycord);
```

I want to save it's output (aka "Player coordinates (0,0)") into an NSString.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done like that:

```
NSString *yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Player cordinates(%i, %i)", xcord, ycord];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying a plain old NSString and didn't think about stringWithFormat. Stackoverflow is telling me to wait to accept the answer.